# Cannot get proper response in xhttp in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am using following AJAX code

```
  {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (this.readyState == 4 ) {
        alert("Status : " + this.status);
        alert("Response : " + this.responseText);
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xhttp.send(null);
}
```

The problem is that I am unable to get the response. The responseText has no value and status is 0.

I checked in fiddler, the request is properly completed. Fiddler shows the correct response. I checked it by debugging on console, the xhttp doesnot update after xhttp.send().

This code is running inside an IFrame.

Comment: Are you trying to make a cross-origin request? Check your `net` panel on chrome.

Comment: use `console.log(` instead of `alert(`

Comment: @caramba — Why?

Comment: @caramba — It's a simple string. It won't.

Comment: @Quentin it's a suggestion to speed up the debugging process.

Comment: I can't think of any explanation for this behaviour which isn't accompanied by additional information on the Console of the Developer Tools. You need to check them again and look for error messages.

Comment: I vote to close because the OP must verify the logs and then share the result, further, it's impossible to reproduce this issue without sufficient code, entry data, Etc.

Comment: Try using the .onload function you can get the response on that. for example 
`xhttp.onload = function () {`
 ` // Do something with the retrieved data ( found in xhttp.response )`
`};`

Comment: @Faraz Sarwar  there is nothing in xhttp.response

Comment: log xhttp inside onload function see if you getting something or not.

Comment: shouldnt it be `xhttp.responseText` instead of `this.responseText`

Comment: @fcalderan Agreed, it seems like a cross-origin issue. [Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/khof2fgq/).

Comment: @fcalderan I get this error on console "Failed to load http://vagrant.ptcnet.ptc.com:2280/Windchill/wtcore/getWtProperties.jsp?prop=wt.server.hostname: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9999' is therefore not allowed access." I guess this happens because I am trying to access "http://vagrant.ptcnet.ptc.com:2280/Windchill/wtcore/getWtProperties.jsp?prop=wt.server.hostname"  from an Iframe where the iframe belongs to "http://localhost:9999". How can I make it possible?

Comment: you need to be in control of the server and allow a cross-origin request (e.g for apache: https://poanchen.github.io/blog/2016/11/20/how-to-enable-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-an-apache-server)

Comment: @fcalderan is there anything that I can do at the client domain to resolve the issue?